# How to create a probability distribution from 0 to 1 that declines?

Tags: probability

(Assume I have access to a Random function that generates a real number between $0$ and $1$)

If I wanted a uniform distribution as follows, I would just generate the random number from $0$ to $1$.

[image: Uniform distribution]

How would I create a distribution that goes from $0$ to $1$, but instead of "flat", it slopes down a $y = -x +1$ line?

[image: What I'm trying to create]

Thanks!

Comment: Pick two numbers 0-1. If the first is less than the second, then your random number is the first. If not, pick another two numbers 0-1.

Comment: Very elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed probability density function is
$$ f_X(x) \stackrel?= \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1 - x & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

This doesn't quite work, because the integral of a probability density over the entire number line has to be $1,$ and yours gives an integral of just $\frac12.$

You can fix this by making your interval larger or by increasing your density function. I assume you want the same interval and  the same relative proportions of probabilities, so the solution is just to multiply by $2$:
$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
2 - 2x & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Integrate $\int f_X(x)\, \mathrm dx$ to get the distribution function:
$$ F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
2x - x^2 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
1 & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$

That is, over a long sequence of trials, if $0\leq x \leq 1$ we expect
$(2x - x^2) \times 100\%$ of the random values to be less than
or equal to $x.$

Using this fact, we can figure out a percentile chart of the distribution.
For example, if you want a number in the $75$th percentile,
choose $x = \frac12,$ because $F_X(\frac12) = 0.75.$

Now the idea is to take your uniform random number generate and use it to generate a kind of "percentile" figure, then use that "percentile" to decide what random number you get.

Let $y = 2x  -  x^2 = 1 - (x - 1)^2.$
Solving for $x,$ there are two possible solutions, but only one
gives us values of $x$ between $0$ and $1$ when $0 \leq y \leq 1$,
with $x$ increasing as $y$ increases,
and this solution is $x = 1 - \sqrt{1 - y}.$

So pick a number $y$ uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1,$
then set $x = 1 - \sqrt{1 - y}$ and return $x$ as your random number.

This works because for any number $x_1$ that you might choose,
the probability that $x < x_1$ when generated by this random procedure is the same as the probability that $x < x_1$ according to your distribution
(insofar as the "random" number $y$ from your uniform random number generator is really random).

A method like this works for a wide variety of random distributions, not just this example. It's just a little tricky sometimes to solve for $x$ in $y = F_X(x).$
Not so tricky for your distribution, however.